Error NG0303 Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'nav' - Angular 18
I am creating a project in Angular 18. For now, I am only working on the frontend, but I need to create a "test" login. The problem I have is that the navbar was showing in my "login" component. I managed to hide it using a navbar.service.ts and a BehaviorSubject. Now the navbar does NOT show on my "login" page. However, when I click on "log in," the navbar still does not appear, so I cannot navigate between my components.
navbar.component.html:1 NG0303: Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'nav' (used in the '_NavbarComponent' component template).
1. If 'nav' is an Angular component and it has the '*ngIf' input, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component.

I already import CommonModule on navbar.component.ts
import { Component, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { NavbarService } from '../../services/nav.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnDestroy {
  showNavbar = true;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private navbarService: NavbarService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.subscription = this.navbarService.showNavbar.subscribe(value => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showNavbar = value;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }, 0);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

And this is my app.component.html
<app-navbar *ngIf="true"></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

Check that the CommonModule was imported into my components and the service is injected correctly.

If you're starting a v18 project, you should be using the new control flow syntax (@if) instead of the directive based *ngIf control flow :
@if(true) {
   <app-navbar />
}

